# Confusing CPIO problem copying filesystems

Tags: command-line

For decades, on many Unix variant, I used the following to backup.

```
find /source/directory | cpio -dumpv /destination/directory
```

Lately on Ubuntu, this fails in a strange way:
Instead of creating the destination directory, it creates some strange data file.
In addition, it outputs (for every file in the input list)"Cannot Create destination/directory:  file exists.
If I am not mistaken, the destination file is the last one copied over.
Summary:  Very recently cpio(1) pass through fails to create directories.

Additional Data:

```
CPIO(1) version: cpio (GNU cpio) 2.13
Ubuntu  Version: Started as 20.4 and kept up with automatic upgrade.
```

(How do you obtain Ubuntu version?)

If I use long form (getopts) it seems to work:

```
cat /tmp/list | cpio --pass-through --make-directories --preserve-modification-time --unconditional /bu/Nightly/20220618
```

BUT it still does not create directories.
It appears there was a change made in the last week or so.

```
#file /usr/bin/cpio
/usr/bin/cpio: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=419bee4eb6cf7238d4e5ee8cda5657310719b634, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

File Systems:  ZFS everywhere
{zpool,zfs} version:

```
#zfs version
zfs-2.0.6-1ubuntu2.1
zfs-kmod-2.0.6-1ubuntu2.1
```

I know there are other methods of accomplishing the same, but my eyesight is very poor and
I really do not want to dig into shell scripts that are decades old.
I know this method worked in the past (two weeks ago), with Ubuntu.
I have terabytes of archives I cannot update anymore.

The problem is clearly in cpio(1).  The find(1) piping into it can be replaced with a file listing the content, or even typing the filenames directly.

Comment: What exactly is the "strange" data file (what does `file strange-data-file` report)? What version of Ubuntu and of cpio?

Comment: I updated above; it appears the file on the output is simply the last file processed by cpio.  This changes about 500 times per second :-)

Comment: cpio seems to work for me, same version on 22.04, but the file command gives a different sha1 hash.  Maybe reinstall cpio?  How full is your target device? On an ext4 fs, not zfs.

Comment: #ls -al /usr/bin/cpio
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 138K Aug 23  2021 /usr/bin/cpio*

Comment: I added --verbose which confirms cpio copies each file in th e list (stdin) into the destination,  This is WRONG.  It is supposed to copy the files hierarchy into an identical /one on the destination.  I have no idea why the behavior changed.

Comment: disk space in both pools/filesystems is 12TB in the input, 16TB in the output, fill level is about 50%..  Last successful run of the script was 28-Apr-2022.  Then the script was aborted by full fs on the destination.  I added 8TB to it, only to get this nasty gift.